# Mono/Linux and wininet.dll

Tags: c#, mono, wininet

I've got a commandline C# program that compiles and runs fine using Visual C# 2010 and Windows 7. It also compiles and starts fine on Linux/Mono (2.10), but then sits there. (The program is using a 3rd party DLL to fetch data from a remote server.)

Running it in the debugger, I saw it seemed to be waiting for a DNS lookup. So I did the DNS lookup for it, pasted in the IP address. But it still hangs, and breaking into the debugger shows three threads all sitting there waiting:

- `System.Threading.Monitor.Wait`  (timeout set to -1)
- `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`
- `System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne`

I used [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to analyze the DLL. I'm not sure how accurate that is, because it matches against Mono 2.8, and I'm using 2.10.8.1, but it says `Socket.Dispose()` is a missing method. Then 32 [MonoTodo] items, 30 of which are Type.op_Equality or Type.op_Inequality. The other two are `CredentialCache.get_DefaultCredentials()` and `MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen()`.

But what got my attention was, at the bottom of the report, there are two entries for `GetWindowsSocksProxy`, which turns into `SingleServerConnection.InternetQueryOption`, and the P/Invoke library is wininet.dll. Could this be related?

So, is there anything I can do? E.g. can I copy that DLL from a windows machine to my linux machine? If so, where do I put it?

P.S. I wondered about connectivity issues. So I made a quick test Mono using `WebClient`, which worked fine. But one interesting difference is the non-working script loads "/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll [External]" at the point where it first needs to connect to something. But my WebClient never did that.

Comment: Have you gone through this? http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability It is the bible you need to digest.

Comment: @LexLi I just read it properly, and it just says P/Invoke calls needs to be adapted. As the DLL I have is closed source that isn't an option. But does that mean I'm out of options?

Comment: Almost. Unless you can completely replace it with a fully managed solution. I don't recommend Mono + Wine, as I doubt anyone seriously uses it or test it.

Comment: If it's only one or two p/invoke calls, it may be feasible to implement it for linux in C. That said, missing dlls/functions normally throw an exception, as such your problem seems to be different. You should examine the stack trace for the threads to see where they are called from.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. Re "missing dlls/functions should [crash]" was also what I expected. I tried using mono under wine, with identical results (for binaries compiled with mono, and compiled with Visual Studio).